# cannot add individual links to images in javascript slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascrpit slider for a clients site and I cant figure out how to link the individual images in the slider. The slider is fully functional and works great besides the linking issue.

I find if I remove items from <--ul class="items"-->(below) I am able to link the <--li--> images and have them act as normal links but then I lose the javaslider function. I have tried literally everything.

My goal is to link each of the images to its respective page on the site. There are 4 total images. I'm pretty new with this stuff so any help would be awesome.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.gallery')._TMS({
      show:0,
      pauseOnHover:true,
      prevBu:'.prev',
      nextBu:'.next',
      playBu:'.play',
      duration:700,
      preset:'fade',
      pagination:$('.img-pags').uCarousel({show:4,shift:0}),
      pagNums:false,
      slideshow:7000,
      numStatus:true,
      banners:false,
      waitBannerAnimation:false,
      progressBar:false 



      })        
 })
```

Website

```
    <div class="container_12">
      <div class="grid_12">
        <div id="slide">                
            <div class="gallery">
            <ul class="items">

                    <li><a href="about.html"><img src="images/gallery-big-1.jpg" alt="">     </a></li>

                    <li><img src="images/gallery-big-5.jpg" alt=""></li>

                    <li><img src="images/gallery-big-2.jpg" alt=""></li>

                    <li><img src="images/gallery-big-6.jpg" alt=""></li>
               </ul>

            </div>
            <a href="#" class="prev"></a><a href="#" class="next"></a>
        </div>      
      </div>



#slide {  width:940px; height:415px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; z-index:2; }

.gallery {
width:940px;
position:relative;
z-index:2
}
.items {display:none;}
.pag { position:relative;}
.img-pags {position:static; left:0px; z-index:1; display:block;}
.img-pags ul {margin:0}
.img-pags li { width:200px; height:170px; margin-right:20px; display:block;     overflow:hidden;  }
.img-pags li a {position:relative;display:block;border:#f4f4f4 5px solid; }
.img-pags li a img {}
.img-pags li a span{ display:block; background:#fff;}
.img-pags li.active a,.img-pags li a:hover{border:#CCC 5px solid;}
.img-pags li.active a img,.img-pags li a:hover img{}
.prev {background:url(../images/prev-1.gif) 0 0 no-repeat; bottom:1px; left:1px;      display:block; position:absolute; width:44px;height:44px; z-index:9999;}
.next{background:url(../images/next-1.gif) 0 0 no-repeat; bottom:1px; right:1px; display:block; position:absolute; width:44px;height:44px; z-index:9999;}
.prev:hover, .next:hover {background-position: 0 bottom;}
```

Comment: Obviously you haven't tried "literally everything" or it would be working. :-) What slider are you using? How about a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Welcome to SO! A JSFiddle is usually appreciated by in our community. It helps us get a better understanding of your code.

Comment: Lol. you're right, It feels like thus far I have tried everything that I know, which is very little. I am working from a template and it (slider / uCarousel.js) was provided in the set. I was given the template and asked to change a few things around to make the small business owner happy. I pretty much understand the html and css but really have no idea about the javascript.

Comment: span and isherwood, thank you for the jsfiddle.net link. I will look into that and see what comes to. I really Appreciate the help.

Comment: Here is the link from Fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/HcmKW/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap gallery images with jQuery in `<a>` tag, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/TqXdt/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="slide">

  <div class="gallery">

    <ul class="items">

      <li>
        <img src="images/gallery-big-1.jpg" alt="" data-link="http://google.com" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/gallery-big-5.jpg" alt="" data-link="http://jsfiddle.net" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/gallery-big-2.jpg" alt="" data-link="http://stackoverflow.com" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/gallery-big-6.jpg" alt="" data-link="http://api.jquery.com" />
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>

  <a href="#" class="prev"></a> <a href="#" class="next"></a>

</div>
```

**jQuery**

Tip: Put this before `</body>` in your HTML

```
$(function() {

  $('.gallery ul li img').each(function() {

    var imgHref = $(this).attr('data-link');

    $(this).wrap('<a href="' + imgHref + '"</a>');

  });

});
```